# Object passed by reference not working as expected

Tags: c++, function, object

I've got a program with a treeview class, a console class, and an options class.

I'd like to pass the treeview object to the options object, and be able to access dynamic values inside of the treeview (file lists and so on).

I've tried passing by reference, and it compiles, but through a few debug messages, I can tell it's not the same object, so the values are all empty.

Options panel `Init` header:

```
public:
    void Init (HWND, PnlConsole&, PnlTree&);
    ...
private:
    PnlTree tree_;
    PnlConsole console_;
    ...
```

Options panel `Init` function:

```
void PnlOptions::Init(HWND hwnd0, PnlConsole& console0, PnlTree& tree0) {
    tree_ = tree0;
    console_ = console0;
    ...
```

Instantiation of classes in `main` file:

```
PnlTree pnl_tree;
PnlOptions pnl_options;
PnlConsole pnl_console;
```

Call to `Init` inside `main` function:

```
pnl_options.Init(hwnd0, pnl_console, pnl_tree);
```

I've been working at this for a long time (as some people have read on my previous questions) and it's very frustrating. Can someone help me to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console0` and `tree0` are being passed by reference into `Init()` but the assigments within the function result in copies of the arguments, due to the types of `tree_` and `console_`.

It is not possible to change the types of `tree_` and `console_` in this context because `Init()` is not the constructor and reference types must be assigned immediately (in the constructor initializer list).

A solution would be to make the types pointers and take the addresses of the arguments. Note that there is a lifetime requirement in that the objects referred to by `console0` and `tree0` must exist for as long as the `PnlOptions` requires them.

Comment: OK, thanks very much, I'll keep trying.  This language is killing me slowly...everything seems extremely more difficult than it should be...just today I'm learning about things suddenly getting copied everywhere without my knowing it :p

Comment: `Note that there is a lifetime requirement in that the objects referred to by console0 and tree0 must exist for as long as the PnlOptions requires them.`  Not entirely sure what you mean here but I'll probably hit this wall tomorrow.  Things are apparently destroyed without my knowing it also...

Comment: @Steve, if the object referred to by `console0` is destructed by something outside of the `PnlOptions`, instance that has a pointer to `console0`, then `PnlOptions` has a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Comment: OMG finally got it.  That only took 4 hours.  But I guess that's the "pointer hell" everyone talks about.  Older and wiser.

Answer (score 2):

From above code, pnl_console and pnl_tree passed to init seems to be structures, so they will exist only for time, when block with Init function will exist.

In your Init function, you are passing reference via &, but assigned it to structure. I would recomend, pass it with *

```
 void PnlOptions::Init(HWND hwnd0, PnlConsole * console0, PnlTree * tree0)

 PnlTree * pnl_tree;
 PnlOptions pnl_options;
 PnlConsole * pnl_console;

 pnl_options.Init(hwnd0, &pnl_console, &pnl_tree);
```

Comment: If objects are really defined as OP says, `pnl_console` and `pnl_tree` will exist for as long as `pnl_options` exists.

Comment: Bad order of sentences :) By "above code" was meant code in original post... I edited my answer, thanks